react-hook-form: isDirty doesn't work at the first time
I recently try react-hook-form, and got an issue
You can have a look at my Codesanbox
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/youthful-wiles-cm8cf6
And, type the text "1" to the input and immediately click the button "check", you can see the log that isDirty is false
I think isDirty in this situation would be true, wouldn't it?

You can wrap your check function with useCallback to ensure it recreated on isDirty changes:
  const check = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(formState.isDirty);
      console.log(formState.isDirty);
    },
    [formState.isDirty]
  );

Or you can specifically select isDirty from formState:
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { isDirty },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "",
      // lastName: "Luo"
    },
  });



tried both of your ways and they worked. thank you. but, can you explain more about them, how can they work? Edit: I understand the 1st solution, just curious about the 2nd one
